# Android active link of url in TextView

Tags: android, url, textview

I have getting dynamic text from a web service and showing the same in a TextView. Sometimes the TextView has url like `<a href="http://hello.com">hello</a>`. I have set the text using the following code.

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(sampletext));
```

And also set `android:autoLink="web"` in the corresponding xml of that contains the `TextView`. Now the link is showing properly with blue color and underline, but I found the its just a dead link. Nothing is happening if we try to click it. What I have to do to make the link active?

Answer (score 170, accepted):

After revisiting all solutions, a summary with some explanations:

```
android:autoLink="web"
```

will find an URL and create a link even if android:linksClickable is not set, links are by default clickable. You don't have to keep the URL alone, even in the middle of a text it will be detected and clickable.

```
<TextView
    android:text="My web site: www.stackoverflow.com"
    android:id="@+id/TextView1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:autoLink="web">
</TextView>
```

To set a link via the code, same principle, no need for pattern or android:autoLink in layout, the link is found automatically using Linkify:

```
  final TextView myClickableUrl = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myClickableUrlTextView);
  myClickableUrl.setText("Click my web site: www.stackoverflow.com");
  Linkify.addLinks(myClickableUrl, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
```

Comment: Another thing to put here is that if you need more than web links, you can use the `all` attribute, which supports all types of links.

Answer (score 36):

This works for me:

```
<TextView
    android:text="www.hello.com"
    android:id="@+id/TextView01"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:autoLink="web">
</TextView>
```

Comment: I used this...but it is giving with blue color and underlined text, but I found the its just a dead link. No click action is happening. That is my problem.

Comment: i know this is old, you need to set clickable true and define onclick function

Answer (score 14):

To Save any one time the true solution is

```
    <TextView
    android:text="www.hello.com"
    android:id="@+id/TextView01"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:autoLink="web"
    android:linksClickable="true">
</TextView>
```

and i use it and it work perfect

Answer (score 9):

There are 2 cases:

- the text looks like `"click on http://www.hello.com"`

then you just have to set the **autoLink** attribute in the xml so that the link is automatically detected in the text:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:autoLink="web"
    android:text="click on http://www.hello.com"/>
```

- the text looks like `click on <a href="http://hello.com">hello</a>`

then you have to do it by code and tell the text is html, and specify a Link movement method for the click:

```
    String text = "click on <a href=\"http://hello.com\">hello</a>";
    TextView textView = view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
    textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Answer (score 4):

Check out this approach:

```
String text = "Visit stackoverflow.com";
TextView label = new TextView(this);
label.setText(text);
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("stackoverflow.com");
Linkify.addLinks(label, pattern, "http://");
```

Answer (score 3):

i have give some idea which i have found it

```
TextView tv = ( TextView ) findViewById( R.id.link );  
    WebView wv = ( WebView ) findViewById( R.id.webView );  
    URLSpan[] urlSpans = tv.getUrls();  
    for ( URLSpan urlSpan : urlSpans )  
    {  
        wv.loadUrl( urlSpan.getURL() );  
    }
```

string.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<resources>  
  <string name="app_name">Hello, Android</string>  
  <string name="link">'<a href="http://www.google.com" rel="nofollow">Google</a>'</string>  
</resources>
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<LinearLayout  
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
        android:orientation="vertical"  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
        >  

  <TextView  
          android:id="@+id/link"  
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
          android:autoLink="all"  
          android:linksClickable="true"  
          android:text="@string/link" />  

  <WebView  
          android:id="@+id/webView"  
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
          android:layout_weight="1.0" />  

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: for the link string tag value in string.xml, ensure you escape the following characters, else the project might fail to build. & change to &amp;   < change to &lt;   > change to &gt;

Answer (score 2):

In your XML, you need to add `android:linksClickable="true"` in the TextView.

Answer (score 0):

If you are displaying in textview the string from strings.xml, strings containing the web link should not have word "a href=". If these words are deleted from the strings.xml file then the link will work.

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines of code to your `textView` in `xml` File it will work perfectly fine..

`android:autoLink="web"
android:textColorLink="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
android:linksClickable="true"`

or if want a your own link in `textview`  add these lines of code  in your java file

```
  final SpannableString s = new SpannableString("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cn.wps.moffice_eng");
  Linkify.addLinks(s, Linkify.ALL);
```

set this 's' String in your `TextView` by function

```
Textview.setText(s);
```

and don't forget to add  this line

```
 ((TextView)findViewById(android.R.id.message)).setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

id will be your `textview` id

Enjoy ...

Answer (score 0):

[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47742094/925135) is right, BUT not complete, because I had in my xml some properties from other answers like autoLink and linksClickable and programatic way did not work. Also when I passes string with html  from string resource also it did not work, so beware, you have to clean your xml and pass string directly exactly as in that answer.

```
    String text = "click on <a href=\"http://hello.com\">hello</a>";
    TextView textView = view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
    textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

I did not try it without without LinkMovementMethod but now I am ok as it finally work. Other answers did not work for me or was for visible url text, not clickable text as link.