# How to implement a OnClick for a text/link which is in a TextView

Tags: android, textview, onclicklistener

I have a `TextView` where it contains a text, link and `emailID`, as shown in the `ScreenShot`:

[image]

I want to implement it such that when a user clicks on the link, it should open the browser and EmailId opens SendMail.

I can not opening the browser and send email, but I want to implement a `click` functionality for only particular `text`, that is, `Link` and `EmailID` in that `TextView`, not for the entire `TextView`.

Is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android active link of url in TextView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910703/android-active-link-of-url-in-textview)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use built-in linkify. Read this tutorial, easy to understand:

[Linkify text link url in TextView text Android example](http://android.okhelp.cz/linkify-text-link-url-in-textview-text-android-example/)

These post also may help you [Android Linkify text - Spannable Text in Single Text View - As like Twitter tweet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7570239/android-linkify-text-spannable-text-in-single-text-view-as-like-twitter-twee)

and [Android: ClickableSpan in clickable TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183645/android-clickablespan-in-clickable-textview)

**And here is complete code using Spannable :**

```
final String webAddress = "www.123456.org";
final String emailAddress = "info@123456.com";
TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);      

Spannable span = Spannable.Factory.getInstance().newSpannable("For more details on the app visit us at " + webAddress + " or write to us at " + emailAddress);   

ClickableSpan webClickSpan = new ClickableSpan() {  
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {  
         Uri uriUrl = Uri.parse("http://" + webAddress); 
         Intent launchBrowser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriUrl);
         startActivity(launchBrowser);
    } };

ClickableSpan emailClickSpan = new ClickableSpan() {  
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {  
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setType("message/rfc822");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{emailAddress});
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "email body.");

            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send Email"));
        } };


 span.setSpan(webClickSpan, 40, 40 + webAddress.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

 span.setSpan(emailClickSpan, 73, span.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

 text.setText(span);

 text.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Answer (score 2):

It is achievable through a `Spannable` object. `Spannable` allows you to add markups to a portion of text and also, to *attach* a `ClickableSpan`, that will be fired when you press on the span.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Class Linkify:

```
Linkify.addLinks(yourTextView, Linkify.ALL);
```

or just for URLs:

```
Linkify.addLinks(yourTextView, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
```