# How to make links of HtmlSpan clickable?

Tags: android, textview, spannablestring

I have simple task: to display in `TextView` some HTML code.

The implementation is:

```
   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subtitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#808080"
        android:textSize="16.5dip"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="4dip"/>
```

And the code:

```
    mSubtitle.setText(Html.fromHtml(mData.answer));
```

Here is example of the `mData.answer`:

```
Some text <a href="url1">link1</a>, some text <a href="url2">link2</a>, etc
```

I suppose this is not so heavy code to display in the `TextView`. And it works, but links in my `TextView` are not clickable. How to enable this feature?

Comment: Put this in your `TextView` : `android:linksClickable="true"` or check that http://stackoverflow.com/a/17544212/1106598
Plus, there are tons of questions like this. Please check them before you post any question

Comment: @GokhanArik this is not same question. Most of them operating with one single link in text, which is unacceptable in this case. And I've tried to apply this attributes(without results) before posting question.

Comment: It doesn't matter, logic is the same. I posted answer now check and let me know

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/subtitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#808080"
        android:textSize="16.5dip"
        android:autoLink="web"
        android:linksClickable="true"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="4dip"/>
        />
```

`autoLink` will solve your problem, if it doesn't try this also

```
mSubtitle.setText(Html.fromHtml(mData.answer));
mSubtitle.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```