# Is there a way to detect a string containing the URL?

Tags: ios

I am doing chat function, my company asked to detect chat content whether containing the URL? Then I can highlight the url and click to jump to the url web site!Can you help  me? Thank you very much.

Comment: Use the regex public static final String `URL_REGEX = "^((https?|ftp)://|(www|ftp)\\.)?[a-z0-9-]+(\\.[a-z0-9-]+)+([/?].*)?$";`

Comment: Please check the following answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910703/android-active-link-of-url-in-textview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can using your own regex or simply using **android.Text.util.Linkify** class like this:

```
TextView textContent;
String content; 
textContent.setText(content);
Linkify.addLinks(textContent, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
```

if you want to make it automatically check phone number, email, etc., you can use **Linkify.ALL** on the second paramter.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your method is automatic detection of the Android system. Can you point out the specific method to detect ? Or how the Android system is detected.I am using IOS.Even if the language is different, but I believe that the method process is certainly similar.

Comment: Oh, i suspect you are on android because of the android tag. If you would implement that on another platform you can simply do by implement your own URL regex, or check on android.Text.util.Linkify class on Android how it   perform URL matcher.

Answer (score 1):

By using Regular expressions you can find string contains url or not. use this following code.

```
public static final String URL_REGEX = "^((https?|ftp)://|(www|ftp)\\.)?[a-z0-9-]+(\\.[a-z0-9-]+)+([/?].*)?$";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(URL_REGEX);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("google.com");//replace with string to compare
if(matcher.find()) {
   Log.i("String contains URL");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But your answer can only be detected in a certain web site, and can not detect a string containing all the urls. And the position and length of the string can not be found and marked for clicking.