# Set hyperlink inside TextView in C# Android App

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm beginner. I want to add hyperlink to TextView like this: 
some_text [hyperlink] some_text.

```
<TextView
    android:text="Please read our *rules and conditions* before using app."
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:autoLink="web" />
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android active link of url in TextView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910703/android-active-link-of-url-in-textview)

Comment: I want the text be different from the actual url

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that programmatically. Remove the `autoLink` attribute from TextView.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

In your Activity class,

```
TextView textView = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView);
textView.TextFormatted = Html.FromHtml("Please read our " +
                "<a href=\"http://www.xamarin.com\">Rules and Conditions</a> " +
                "before using app.");

textView.MovementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.Instance;
```

Comment: This is deprecated now!

Comment: Now you have to add FromHtmlOptions enum inside FromHtml methode for not be deprecated, like:

textView.TextFormatted = Html.FromHtml("Please read our " +
                "<a href=\"http://www.xamarin.com\">Rules and Conditions</a> " +
                "before using app.", FromHtmlOptions.ModeLegacy);